# Non type type parameters

Tags: haxe

What if I have classes that are different only by some constant used in code. Is it possible to have one generic implementation without runtime cost?

Here is the example (it's a little bit too long...)

```
@:enum abstract Param(Int) {
    var foo = 0;
    var bar = 1;
}

class WorkBase {

    public function new() {}

    private inline function work_impl(p: Param): Void {

        if(p == foo) {
            trace('foo');
        }
        else {
            trace('bar');
        }
    }

    public function work(): Void {

    }
}

class WorkFoo extends WorkBase{
    override public function work(): Void {
        work_impl(foo);
    }
}

class WorkBar extends WorkBase {
    override public function work(): Void {
        work_impl(bar);
    }
}

class Test {

    public static function main() {
        var workFoo = new WorkFoo();
        var workBar = new WorkBar();
        workFoo.work();
        workBar.work();
    }
}
```

After compilation with `-D analyzer-optimize` we will see that `WorkFoo.work()` and `WorkBar.work()` functions were optimized and contain only one branch of code that matches one of the `Param` values. In real life there are lot of such comparisons in `work_impl()`, and they all are optimized out. That's good.

But what if I do not want to create `WorkFoo` and `WorkBar` by hand. Is it possible to do something like this:

```
@:generic
class WorkBase<PARAM> {
    private inline function work_impl(p: Param): Void {
        ...
    }

    public function work(): Void {
        work_impl(PARAM);
    }
}
```

The closest thing I know is [const-type-parameter](https://haxe.org/manual/macro-generic-build.html#const-type-parameter). But I do not feel generic build is a good choice here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The closest thing I know is const-type-parameter. But I do not feel generic build is a good choice here.

Const type parameters can be used without `@:genericBuild` - a const type parameter in combination with `@:generic` is enough to get the desired optimization:

```
@:enum abstract Param(Int) from Int {
    var foo = 0;
    var bar = 1;
}

@:generic class Work<@:const PARAM:Int> {
    public function new() {}

    public function work():Void {
        if (PARAM == foo) {
            trace('foo');
        } else {
            trace('bar');
        }
    }
}

class Main {
    public static function main() {
        var workFoo = new Work<0>();
        var workBar = new Work<1>();
        workFoo.work();
        workBar.work();
    }
}
```

Due to `@:generic`, one class is generated for each constant value, for instance on JS the output looks like this:

```
var Work_$0 = function() {
};
Work_$0.prototype = {
    work: function() {
        console.log("source/Main.hx:11:","foo");
    }
};
var Work_$1 = function() {
};
Work_$1.prototype = {
    work: function() {
        console.log("source/Main.hx:13:","bar");
    }
};
```

Note that this example fails with a "constraint check failure" in Haxe 3.4.7 for some reason, but works fine with Haxe 4 preview 4 and later. Another limitation is that neither `new Work<Param.foo>()` nor `new Work<foo>()` work - you need to pass the actual constant value.

Comment: Great. Is this documented somewhere? I mean ability to specify type for type parameters and @:const metadata.

Comment: It's possible to make it work in Haxe 3.4. http://try-haxe.mrcdk.com/#98A69

Comment: `@:const` might not be documented in the manual yet. The feature was originally added in response to https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/3450. Specifying a type is simply a constraint (https://haxe.org/manual/type-system-type-parameter-constraints.html).